If $\mathfrak q$ is a $P$-primary ideal, and $x \notin \mathfrak q$ then $(\mathfrak q:x)$ is $P$-primary.
I’m trying to understand the following proof of the following result. I certainly understand it, but I am confused about certain aspects of the proof.
Let $A$ a ring commutative with identity. Let $\mathfrak{q}$ a $P$-primary ideal and $x \in A$ such that $x \notin \mathfrak{q}$. Then $(\mathfrak{q}:x)$ is a $P$-primary ideal.
It’s easy to see that $r(\mathfrak{q}:x)=p$, my confusion does not lie there.
By definition $(\mathfrak q:x)=\left \{ s \in A | sx \in \mathfrak{q} \right \}$.
Now, let $yz \in (\mathfrak{q}:x)$. I want to prove that $y \in (\mathfrak{q}:x)$ or $z^n \in (\mathfrak{q}:x)$ for some $n$.
If $y \notin (\mathfrak{q}:x) \implies yx \not \in \mathfrak{q}$. But $yzx \in q$ however, how can I deduce from here that $z^n \in \mathfrak{q}$ for some $n$?
We can deduce that $(zx)^m \in \mathfrak{q}$ for some $m$, but that implies that $z^m \in \mathfrak{q}$ or $(x)^{mk} \in \mathfrak{q}$ for some $m$ and some $k$.
In Atiyah, he write, $xyz \in \mathfrak{q}$ and written like this, the proof works perfectly. Nevertheless, this doesn't fit with the definition of the quotient.

You started with $yz \in (\mathfrak{q}: x)$, you wanted to prove $y \in (\mathfrak{q}: x)$ or there is some $n$ with $z^n \in (\mathfrak{q}: x)$. You assumed $y \not \in (\mathfrak{q}: x)$, which means $xy \not \in \mathfrak{q}$, so you need to prove there is some $n$ with $z^n \in (\mathfrak{q}: x)$ under this assumption.
Now you have $yzx \in \mathfrak{q}$ and so therefore it's certainly also the case that $(xy)z \in \mathfrak{q}$ since these are literally the same element of this commutative ring. Since $(xy) \not \in \mathfrak{q}$, and $\mathfrak{q}$ is primary, we must have $z^n \in \mathfrak{q}$ for some $n$, and since $\mathfrak{q} \subset (\mathfrak{q}: x)$, we are done.
I think what is bothering you is that the definition of primary is weirdly asymmetric, but it doesn't make any of the above reasoning invalid.

I thought that the fact of $z^n \in q$ for some $n$ could be deduced from $(zx)^m$.
